# A special family of ages

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge

A family decides to meet up.

> Anthony is 96 years old
>
> Bernard is 80 years old
>
> Barry is 24 years old
>
> Melanie is 60 years old.
>
> How old is Helen and why are they a family?

Comment: Bernard reminds me of George Bernard Shaw and Helen reminds me of Helen Keller.... But nothing to connect them

Comment: Barry reminds me of Barry Allen... and Anthony from Raj comics... Anyways, [this says 6999 questions](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest).

Comment: @ABcDexter, damn it a question must have been deleted. This *was* the 7000th

Comment: @ABcDexter, now it says 6997! :P I give up...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here goes:

> The given names are "nicknames" of cities that hosted the Summer Olympics, and the age is how long ago they hosted
>
>  **Ant**hony (96) : **Ant**werp in 1920
>  **Ber**nard (80) : **Ber**lin in 1936
>  **Bar**ry (24) : **Bar**celona in 1992
>  **Mel**anie (60) : **Mel**bourne in 1956

So Helen is:

> Helsinki in 1940, making her 76

And they are a family

> in that they are all host cities for the Summer Olympic games